# Correct offset of characters with extra white spaces, newlines, etc

Tags: python, string

I am trying to implement a simple solution for offset correction due to 'junk' characters, for example:

`string_1 = "London is the capital of the UK"`

-> chars location: `("capital", 14,21)` and `("UK", 29, 31)`

however, in the presence of newlines etc, the char location are changed:

`string_2 = "London       is the\n\ncapital of the\n UK"`

-> chars location `("capital" are (21,28)), ("UK" are (36,38))`

moreover, the string may contain any number of newlines and other artefacts as well as any number of key-words.

**My question** is, given a text with extra characters (ASCII, newlines, etc), and some cleaning function, how to adjust the locations of certain keywords in the cleaned text?

```
string_2 = cleaning_txt(string_1)
```

-> `("capital", 14, 21) --> ("capital", 21, 28)`
-> `("UK", 29, 31) --> ("UK", 36, 38)`

Comment: You need to define exactly what is a "junk character".

Comment: thanks! That might be a bit tricky to define in advance, as the cleaning function may change. So ideally I need to align 'non-junk' characters and find their relative locations.

Comment: Is the cleaning function basically a mapping of chars to junk or not junk? It's not clear, also, if you have a code snippet to demonstrate the problem or your proposed solution it would help

Comment: Thanks Rotem, my basic cleaning function removes some artefact with BeatifulSoup, regex for ASCII and newlines by .splitlines(). So I do not define in advance 'junk' and 'non-junk' tokens (apart from a few, like '@', ± etc). I would like to keep the cleaning function flexible, as I may include more cleaning logic in the future. I'm wondering how to align cleaned (whatever method used) and the original string and to find the relative offset of certain tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.find` works fine for this purpose:

```
string_1 = "London is the capital of the UK"
string_2 = "London       is the\n\ncapital of the UK"

def find_pos(s, match):
    pos = s.find(match)
    return (pos, pos+len(match))

match = 'capital'

find_pos(string_1, match)
# (14, 21)

find_pos(string_2, match)
# (21, 28)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your string this way:

```
x =  "London       is the\n\ncapital of the UK"
x = x.replace('\n','')

while '  ' in x:
    x = x.replace('  ', ' ')

print(x)
```

Gives:

```
London is thecapital of the UK
```

Comment: Hm. As you can see, throwing `\n` away is notagoodidea. It is generally considered [whitespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace), just like regular spaces.